# Does ReSharper 6.1 work with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2012, resharper-6.1

Does Resharper 6.1 support Visual Studio 2012? I have it working with VS2010 but wondering do I need to upgrade to ReSharper 7.0 for support in VS2012. It would be disappointing if I did.

Comment: Major changes were needed for ReSharper to support Visual Studio 2012, so it works only with ReSharper 7.0 or higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install VS2012 after installing VS2010+ReSharper, then the latter does NOT appear in VS2012.

I'm assuming -- I haven't tested this -- that even if you install R# after VS2012 it won't show up either simply because the R# installer does not offer the option to integrate into VS2012.

Therefore, I think R# 6.1 is incompatible with VS2012.

Answer (score 8):

JetBrains [admitted that though Resharper 6.1 integrates well with VS 11, they have missed the installer.](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/11/resharper-61-eap-for-visual-studio-2011/) Here is  [a nice step-by-step explanation](http://gurustop.net/blog/2011/11/11/resharper-6-0-resharper-6-1-vs11-visual-studio-11-support-keyboard-shortcuts/) on how to get it to work with vs 11.