# How to setup ReSharper to vs2012 after setuping it to vs2010

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have setup ReSharper to vs2010.
Howerver,I setup vs2012 right now and find no ReSharper add-in  in vs2012.
How can regist ReSharper to my IDE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Only Resharper 7 or higher will work with Visual Studio 2012, if you have this version then just re-install it and it should show up. Earlier versions will not work. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892764/does-reharper-6-1-work-with-visual-studio-2012) other question about resharper and VS 2012.

Comment: Note that you will need to use the 'Change' button and make sure the 'VS12' checkbox is checked. Do not use the 'Repair' button.  Uninstalling and then re-installing is not required.

Comment: Can we use later version of resharper up to 7.0 i have 7.1.3 can i configure it with VS2012 ?

Comment: @Shashank yes it will, any version above 7 will work for VS2012 (note, you will need Resharper 8 or above for VS2013).