# Installing Resharper plugin to VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, visual-studio-2012

Just installed `Visual Studio 2012` on my Windows 7 pc, how do i get `Resharper` plugin, do i need to give a `nuget` command to install, if so what command can i give for that, or do i need to download some package

I did find these links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892764/does-reharper-6-1-work-with-visual-studio-2012), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225321/how-to-setup-resharper-to-vs2012-after-setuping-it-to-vs2010), but couldnt get the steps to install it ...

Comment: I am running VS2012 ultimate on Win7 x86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the plugin [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html?utm_source=vsgallery&utm_medium=vsgallery-page-downloadpage&utm_campaign=resharper%5d) from `jetBrains`....